# How to understand frames for UIViews with rotation transforms applied?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I've ran into a weird issue when executing the code below for a UIView with rotation transform applied. What I'm trying to do is remove the view from superview, then insert it under a specific view and restore its frame:

```
  UIView* movedView=  [self.views objectAtIndex:newIndex];
    center = movedView.center;

   CGRect oldFrame  = movedView.frame;

    //find the layer on top and insert the moved view under that
    UIView* coveringView = [self.views objectAtIndex:newIndex-1];
    [movedView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:movedView belowSubview:coveringView];
    movedView.frame = oldFrame;
```

I expect that the view would appear in the same place after the operation, but it shifts around, based on how much rotation was applied via CGAffineTransformMakeRotation().

I got the desired behavior by replacing calls that assign frame to calls that assign **center** property. This got me thinking - how can I understand what's happening to a UIView's frame when it is rotated? **Is there a good tutorial or something that can help me conceptually understand how transforms affect UIView's frame?**

Answer (score 4):

[The `-[UIView frame]` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) says this:

> Warning: If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

and this:

> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the `transform` property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the `frame` property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the `center` property and adjust the size using the `bounds` property instead.

So you might want to avoid thinking about the `frame` property at all, since your `transform` is not identity.

Answer (score 4):

After a `CGAffineTransform`, the property `frame` of a `UIView` is simply no longer defined. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) say "Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored."

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the `frame` is calculated by the `center`, the `transform` and the `bounds`

just like the formula: `frame = f(center,transform,bounds)`. But I do not know the internal of the `f(x)`